# Tailwind animation on display

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I am trying to learn how to use animation with Tailwind. The animation that I am trying hopelessly to make is:

```
Entering: "duration-200 ease-out"
  From: "opacity-0 scale-95"
  To: "opacity-100 scale-100"
Leaving: "duration-100 ease-in"
  From: "opacity-100 scale-100"
  To: "opacity-0 scale-95"
```

The element I'm trying to animate is:

```
 <div class="absolute top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 duration-200 ease-out transition transform origin-top-right">
```

Now I'm not quite sure exactly what to do since this animation should only run as soon as it is displayed I've attempted:

```
<div class="absolute top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 duration-200 
ease-out transition transform origin-top-right" style="${this.showMenu ? '' : 'display:none'}">
```

However this doesn't really give me an animated result. What can I try next?

Comment: Are you using a JS framework?

Comment: @JHeth i am using web components :)

Comment: The Tailwind UI docs have a section on [transitions](https://tailwindui.com/documentation#html-transitions) but they have a very strong emphasis on frameworks (Alpine is really the only example illustrated) which take care of adding/removing/switching states for you. You could recreate that concept but it would be quite a bit of work. However, the reason your example is not animating anything is because display is not an animatable property, there might be a way but your example does not have enough to reproduce functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `display:none` and change it to `display:block` it will not fire your animation. You need to display the element first, and then animate. You can do that by setting `display:block` and then use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to apply the animation classes.

```
function onShow() {
 this.isShown = true
 window.requestAnimationFrame( () => {
  this.animationClasses = "opacity-100 scale-100"
 })
}
```

Alternatively, you could hide the element with something like `opacity-0 invisible absolute z-[-1]`, then swap those classes for `opacity-100 visible static` or something similar. Just be careful the element is out of the way when it's hidden, because without `display:none` or `hidden` the element is still on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic style is not usually recommeded. Instead you could use `&&` operator and display only if the `showMenu` is set to `true`

```
{ this.showMenu && <div class="absolute top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 duration-200 
ease-out transition transform origin-top-right"> }
```

Comment: Do you have a working example of this approach? I was trying your code but it doesn't animate